# Ajax call with query string to Asp.net Web Api

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I call api as

```
$.getJSON("/api/accapi/1?p=5&min=10&max=20" , function (json) { 
   ...
});
```

and my ApiController

```
public class AccApiController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/accapi
    public string GetAccApi(string id)
    {
       return id;
    }
}
```

and my route

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I got without my querystrings

```
{"1"}
```

What's missing ?

Answer (score 0):

All you returned was a single parameter, `id`.  According to your route and query string, you have four parameters:

- `id` = 1
- `p` = 5
- `min` = 10
- `max` = 20

But your controller action is ignoring three of them:

```
public string GetAccApi(string id)
```

If you want those other query string values in your controller action, just add them as method parameters:

```
public string GetAccApi(string id, string p, string min, string max)
```

As for your output, what do you want to see?  All of them as a single string?  You *could* do this:

```
return id + p + min + max
```

Which would return this:

```
{"151020"}
```

I doubt that's what you want.  But you'll have to be more explicit about what you *do* want it to return.  Any structure will do.  For example, a custom object:

```
public SomeObject GetAccApi(string id, string p, string min, string max)
{
    return new SomeObject(id, p, min, max);
}
```

Depending on the structure of `SomeObject`, that could come back as:

```
{
  "ID":"1",
  "P":"5",
  "Min":"10",
  "Max":"20"
}
```

Which is at least more structured.  It's up to you what you want to return and in what structure it should be organized.

Comment: Thank you, so can i take it as a whole portion ? Like i want coming parameter as "p=5&min=10&max=20"

Comment: @Melih: Well, you could reconstruct the string like that: `return string.Format("p={0}&min={1}&max={2}", p, min, max);`  To use the actual string that was sent, I suppose you could potentially get it from the `HttpRequest` object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) in the controller, but that's not recommended as it tightly couples the controller to the HTTP context.

Comment: No, i mean, i want to take as a whole of coming parameter from ajax call to api controller like "p=5&min=10&max=20"

Comment: @Melih: That's not how HTTP values work.  You'd need to URL-encode the whole thing into a single value in the actual URL.  Something like: `values=p%3D5%26min%3D10%26max%3D20` and the have a `string values` parameter in the controller action, which would receive the URL-decoded version of that string, which is `"p=5&min=10&max=20"`.